# Searching Across Multiple Tables

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, relational-division

My application has some ***Pages*** which possess some ***Attributes***. ***Pages*** can be ***Linked*** together. I would like my database structure to best support search for ***Links*** which contain certain ***Attributes*** that belong to ***Pages***. Links are a collection of Pages and Page can have many Links.

---

My database stucture is currently as follows

```
PAGE:
    id
    title
    content
```

-

```
ATTRIBUTE:
    id
    page_id
    name
    value
```

-

```
LINK:
    id
    title
```

-

```
PAGE_LINK:
    page_id
    link_id
```

---

So say I had a recipe ***Page*** called *'Mash Potato'* and an ingredients ***Page*** called *'Potato'* that are contained in a ***Link*** called *'Potato Link'*. *'Mash Potato'* has the following ***Attributes*** - *Meal:Dinner, Flavour: Savoury, Difficulty: Easy,* AND *'Potato'* has the ***Attributes*** - *Season: Autumn, Price: Cheap*.

I want to be able to find a link which is *Cheap, Savoury and in Season in Autumn* and get in return the '*Potato Link'*.

---

How do I write that query in SQL and is this the best database structure to query something like this?

Comment: if `PAGE`-to-`LINK` is `one-to-one` (=`LINK` isn't shared by different `PAGE`s) then you should embed `page_id` into `LINK` table.

Comment: What's the meaning of `LINK.title`? Is it a reference to `PAGE.title`? If so, then it's better replaced with `LINK.referred_page_id`. And then there's *really* no need for both `LINK`s table *and* `PAGE_LINK`s table. Use one `LINK`s table with fields `{id, referring_page_id, referred_page_id}`. If you approve my comments I could give an answer with an according SQL query.

Comment: Maybe `Link` wasn't the best name for the table. A `Link` is a collection `Pages` all linked together. A `Page` can have many Links and a `Link` contains many `Pages`. `Link.title` is the name/title of the `Link` not the `Page`.

Comment: For Example: `Pages` called dog, cat, mouse, goldfish may all belong to 'pets' `Link` but dog, cat & mouse may also belong to a 'mammals' `Link`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your attributes are attached to pages. So, you can search for pages that have certain attributes, by checking if those Attributes exist for a page. Finding the pages would look like this:

```
Select Page.ID
From Page
where EXISTS
 (Select * 
  From Attributes
  Where Page_Id = Page.ID
    and (     (Name = 'Season' and Value = 'Autumn')
          or  (Name = 'Flavour' and Value = 'Savory')
          ... etc. ...
        )
```

If you want to find the Links, then you can join this to PAGE_LINK (and even to LINK, if you like).

```
Select Page.ID
From Page
 Join Page_Link PL on PL.Page_ID = Page.ID
 Join Link on Link.ID = PL.Link_ID
where EXISTS
 (Select * 
  From Attributes
  Where Page_Id = Page.ID
    and (     (Name = 'Season' and Value = 'Autumn')
          or  (Name = 'Flavour' and Value = 'Savory')
          ... etc. ...
        )
```